# Receiving a string, checking for a Capital Letter

Tags: c++, string

What Im trying to do is check if the user-supplied string has a capital letter or not.
The first part of the code with the enumerated constant, is just there for another method,
which I got to work using numbers assigned to the words Sunday = 7, Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc. I'm trying have the user not supply numbers, but the actual word (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday), but I want them to specify the day of the week with a capital letter.

Problem I get: compiles fine, but anything you type in is somehow redirected along an execution path that always returns "Retype w/ a capital letter." This happens if I type in fjdkalfda or sunday or Sunday or whatever. Here is the code. Sorry if its not in code format, first time user of Stack Overflow.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){  
    /*enum DaysOfWeek {
        Monday = 1,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday,
        Saturday,
        Sunday
    };*/  //I'm not using this, but I can get my code to work with this
          //enumerated constant by asking the user to input a number corresponding
          //to the day of the week and then using if-else statements to check, say, 
          // int Day;
          // cin >> Day
          // then use if statements to check if Day = a certain number, to give output

    cout << "Enter the day of week with a capital letter: ";
    string Day;
    getline(cin, Day);
    if (Day == ("monday") || ("tuesday"))
        cout << "Retype w/ a capital letter" << endl;
    else if (Day == ("wednesday") || ("thursday"))
        cout << "Retype w/ a capital letter" << endl;
    else if (Day == ("friday") || ("saturday"))
        cout << "Retype w/ a capital letter" << endl;
    else if (Day  == ("sunday"))
        cout << "Retype w/ a capital letter" << endl;
    else
    {
        if (Day == "Monday")
            cout << "Moon" << endl;
        else if (Day == "Tuesday")
            cout << "Mars" << endl;  //continue with the days etc...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (Day == ("monday") || ("tuesday"))` doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: Thanks for the point. I'm just getting the feel for strings with this code and if I separate the "monday" and "tuesday" into separate lines, it works if I type in "Monday" or whatnot. Thanks. I'll be carefull with the logical operator ||, maybe used for just numbers

Comment: You can perform multiple tests on the same line, you just need to use the proper syntax: `if (Day == "monday" || Day == "tuesday")`.  In your example the first if is always true.

Answer (score 1):

One would observe that there is a function called **toupper** which can turn a lower case letter into upper case, and leave an upper case letter alone.   Perhaps you can reuse this function to help solve your problem with less code.

I am inferring from your code that you are only interested in verifying that the first letter is a capital letter.   Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to divert my code into two paths. One making the user retype the day of the week if they say "monday" and the other giving the output if they typed in "Monday." But everything seems to be going down the retype path. If I type in "Monday", im told to retype with a capital letter.

Comment: Well if the ifs are failing, that suggests that get_day does not have the value that you expect.  After the transform, print the value between two angle brackets so you can see what the actual value is.

Answer (score 1):

There is an isupper function in ctype.h that returns true if a `char` is upper case:

```
#include <ctype.h>

...
isCapitalized = isupper(str[0]);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're actually not bothered about capitol letters if we can somehow organize the input choice in an `enum` type. Instead of this `enum classes` would be a better choice if you have `C++11`. If not, it would be quite easy to change this code for normal enums

If you're using gcc/g++, you may need to include prefix `-std=c++11`

Note: you may want to add another `enum` element to `enum class Days` such as `null_day`. Or even better, Make sure user inputs the correct day, until he/she does, don't carry on with program (hint: use `while` loop when using `getline`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

using std::string;
using std::transform;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

// only in C++ 11
enum class Day {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday};    

int main () {  

cout << "Enter the day of week: ";

// store day from user input, transform all to lower case so
// we don't bother with user input type (only error in spelling will be the problem now)
string get_day;
getline(cin, get_day);
transform(get_day.begin(), get_day.end(), get_day.begin(), tolower);

// define instance of enum class Day, and sort out what day user has input
// note that if you do not initialize myDay object, it will set to the first
// element in the enum class Day above (which is Monday). This will happen 
// if user input is not allowed to initialize it. See the << >> section below
Day myDay;
if (get_day == "monday")
    myDay = Day::Monday;
else if (get_day == "tuesday")
    myDay = Day::Tuesday;
else if (get_day == "wednesday")
    myDay = Day::Wednesday;
else if (get_day == "thursday")
    myDay = Day::Thursday;
else if (get_day == "friday")
    myDay = Day::Friday;    
else if (get_day == "saturday")
    myDay = Day::Saturday;
else if (get_day == "sunday")
    myDay = Day::Sunday;
else
    << ERROR CODE HERE >>
    << MAYBE A WHILE LOOP UNTIL USER INPUTS CORRECT DATA >>

// perform your calculations/operations/etc separate from above
if (myDay == Day::Monday)
    cout << "Moon" << endl;

else if (myDay == Day::Tuesday)
    cout << "Mars" << endl;  //continue with the days etc...

return 0;

}
```